# AWS MediaConvert bitrate and quality problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

When I'm trying to use and starting MediaConvert job in CBR, VBR or in QVBR mode with Bitrate or MaxBitrate higher 250 000, getting the error below

Unable to write to output file [s3://***/videos/***/***/original.mp4]: [Failed to write data: Access Denied]

But with Bitrate/MaxBitrate option lower 250 000 transcoding job working fine, but quality is too low. What causing this? Do I need to upgrade that MediaConvert service or I need to add some additional Policies somewhere? All I need is to get videos as avi, etc in mp4 format with the same quality on output as it is on input.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error and found that it was related to having encryption enabled on my bucket defined in the bucket policy.  I build my buckets with Cloudformation and have the following being set in the policy:

```
{
        "Sid": "Deny unencrypted upload (require --sse)",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
            }
        }
    }
```

I have found that having this set in the policy causes some issues with AWS services that write encrypted objects into s3.  So I remove this and then add then set it in the Bucket properties:

[image]

Then I added kms:Decrypt and kms:GenerateDataKey to my Role as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/iam-role.html).  Although, I'm not 100% sure I needed to do that.  But once I did all that, my

> Failed to write data: Access Denied

error was resolved.